# Form/Results Page HTML

Tags: html, forms

I'm working on a form and results page in HTML. This is how the form page looks: [Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guu8M.png)
Once I submit the form, this is how the results page looks: [Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vEe9.png)

The issue I am having is for the 'Read' row in the results page. I don't want 'Books' and 'Phone Apps' to be on two different lines, I want it to be all on one. Like this..

Read: Books, Phone Apps

This is the code that I have for both pages: [Form Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak9sR.png) [Results Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5BOE.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit help center, take tour to see what and How to Ask. For example start by searching your error

Comment: Please read [ask]. In particular the part about not posting pictures of code.

Comment: Alright, I will look into those. Thank you for the help and feedback.

Answer (score -1):

Alright, I'll give this a shot. I suppose part of the issue is that I'm unclear what you want in the end. I believe this is representative and I'll work toward that end:

[image]

One way to accomplish this, and it would work for more complex forms with additional multi-element named groups, would be to insert all the data into a dictionary in one step and then format all the results in another.

```
const resultsList = document.getElementById('results')
let dataObject = {};//this is going to store our data
(window.location.search).forEach((value, name)=>{
    if (not(myObj[name])) {//if this name is new
       dataObject[name]="";//we create an empty string for that name
    }
    dataObject[name] += " "+ value;//we add all values to a named string
})

//after the first loop we have a series of strings 
//with value contents under each name
//in the second loop we will look through all the names
//and print it all as before

let names = dataObject.keys();
names.forEach(n)=>{
   resultsList.append(n+":"+ dataObject[n]);
   resultsList.append(document.createElement('br'));
})
```

Comment: Yeah that was actually what I was asking for. Thank you for answering, this is my first time using Stack Overflow so it was hard to be clear with the question.

Comment: OK that’s good then. Keep in mind that by separating the data gathering from the formatting and publishing you can make other changes as well if you wanted to fancy this up and put things into a table or some sort of a bulleted list all of those options will be open to you

Comment: Alright, I appreciate the help thank you!